# executing a php while server is running (without having to run the webpage)

Tags: php, apache

For a webradio website, I have a php script that fills a playlist text file on every song change.

This is working when at least there is one person at the website.
Cause the php script is triggered when someone uses the website. It checks if the icecast server song is different from the one on the website, and if it does, it calls a function to fill the playlist text file with the new song.

My question is :

Is it possible to execute a script while the server is running, triggered from the server and not from the website ?

While my music is playing on my icecast server, even if no one is using the website, I want my php script to always run in background to fill the playlist text file at every song change. That's why I'm saying 'triggered from the server'.

Is that possible ?

Thanks,

Patrick

Comment: [cron](http://all4wp.blogspot.ca/2008/03/cron-for-dummies.html)

Comment: You can run PHP scripts in CLI mode. You can run this as a cron job if you are running on unix or via Task Sheduler if you are running on Windows